# The cook was fired!

Tags: riddle, word, cipher, poetry

What word am I looking for?

```
The cook is fired! 
Decay! The baker's dozen! 
I need a new job.
```

**Hint #1:**

> The first part includes two elements that must be combined to get to the final word

**Hint #2:**

> Who fires people?

Comment: This isn’t a single word, but is the answer related to rot13(Sevqnl 13 Znepu)?

Comment: @Earlien Haha, no, that's just coincidence. Didn't even notice that! You comment does include something related to the answer though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I get the feeling the word you're looking for is:

> **PURSUE**

Why? Well, (with nods to @hexomino and @LannyStrack for solving parts of the puzzle):

> "The cook is fired!" and "I need a new job." are both key phrases in the puzzle. As pointed out by @hexomino, "Decay! The baker's dozen!" naturally interprets through synonyms as 'rot-13' (*Puzzling*'s favourite encryption method: decay = rot, a baker's dozen = 13). We are therefore looking for a phrase based on the lines used in the riddle that translate to a relevant word when its letters are shifted 13 positions along the alphabet.
>
>  If the recently fired cook (or '**CHEF**' - spotted by @LannyStrack) contacts their Human Resources (or '**HR**') department, then this might be an appropriate step forward in their search for a new career position. But they'll need to be proactive to make sure they find work...
>
>  In other words not only will they need to contact CHEF HR, they will need to **rot13(CHEFHR)** this ambition... i.e. they will need to **PURSUE** it!

Comment: Correct!! Bravo!

Answer (score 27):

I think the word you are looking for is

> Clerk

The cook is fired!

> **Pyrex** = a hard heat-resistant type of glass, typically used for ovenware.

Decay! The baker's dozen!

> This indicates **ROT13** ciphering. If we apply ROT13 to **pyrex** it produces **clerk**

I need a new job.

> **Clerk** = a person employed in an office or bank to keep records, etc.
>  This is your new job.

Comment: And there was me wondering what DK13 might mean ...

Comment: You're getting there! But this isn't the answer I'm looking for! Here's a hint: rot13("Gur pbbx vf sverq" unf gjb ryrzragf sbe fbyivat guvf chmmyr.)

Comment: This is still brilliant.

Answer (score 12):

I think this is worse than my first answer, but I am going to try again.

The cook is fired!

> Synonyms for 'cook' and 'fire' are 'chef' and 'prune' (as in "pruning the staff"). So, I get *chefprune*.

Decay!

> I interpret this as jumbling the letters. Doing that, I get *chepunfre*.

The baker's dozen!

> I interpret this as rot13, giving *purchaser*.

I need a new job.

> The word, and the new job, is **purchaser**.

Original attempt:

> The new job is 'purser'.
>  cook -> 'chef' fired -> 'red' Decay -> chefre
> rot13 -> 'purser'.

Comment: You got the first part! The second part is still incorrect. Hint: rot13(Jub sverf crbcyr?)

Comment: Your first attempt was better. No jumbling! Just the cipher method mentioned by others.